# Mutiple User Conflict : User changes after clicking ok in People Picker/Address book

Tags: 2007, active-directory, people-picker, shared-service-provider

I am trying to add a specific user on a SharePoint Site. While searching for that user in Address book by"Name" say "User A", its showing the correct user. But when i add that user by clicking Ok, the user changes to say "User B". **When searching the user by domain\username (for User A), it only shows two occurrences of  "User B".**

This issue does not occur when i try this on a different server hosted Site with same AD.
Also, i have tried both full and incremental import of user profiles in SSP.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: Does userb exist as a local user as well as the imported user from AD?

Comment: @HughWood: UserB does exist. There is only a single letter difference between both of their usernames. E.g : For UserA- domain\samename1, For UserB-domain\samename

Comment: I was thinking maybe that user exists on two different domains, the one that replicates, so the people picker may be picking it up when it returns the results. Check on the server by looking at a folder permissions and to see if you can see this user once, or even multiple times in a domain or a non domain user even in the wrong place. As you apparently have a duplicate SID somewhere. Was there a domain name change?

Comment: Also check in /_catalogs/users/simple.aspx You are using AD so if it is there it will also duplicate, there was also an issue before of it showing a deleted user that was replicated also

Comment: @HughWood: Thanks a lot for the info. I checked in /_catalogs/users/simple.aspx and i deleted both the users from it. After this, i tried adding again and this time it worked.
Great Help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the details. Old data was conflicting with new one.
I checked in /_catalogs/users/simple.aspx and i deleted both the users from it. After this, i tried adding again and this time it worked. 
Thanks to @HughWood for the help.